# Spark Scala How to replace spacial character from beginning of column name

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame df

> df = source_df.select("data.*").distinct()

> df.show(20,false)

```
---------------+----------------+--------------------------+
id             |_name           |_address  |area           |
--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
222222222222444|null            |india     |Default Value  |
000000000055555|null            |usa       |Default Value  |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

I want to replace spacial character(_) from beginning of column name , and the desire output will be

```
---------------+----------------+--------------------------+
id             |name            |address   |area           |
--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
222222222222444|null            |india     |Default Value  |
000000000055555|null            |usa       |Default Value  |
+--------------+----------------+--------------------------+
```

i have tried with below statement but count not found desire output

df=df.columns.foldLeft(df){(newdf, colname) =>newdf.withColumnRenamed(colname, colname.replace("^_", ""))}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do a rename via a select

```scala
val newCols = df.columns.map(c => col(c) as (if (c.startsWith("_")) c.drop(1) else c))
val newDf = df.select(newCols:_*)
```

This will rename columns starting with `_` and leave columns that don't.  Column order will be maintained as well.

Alternative syntax for the if condition is:

```scala
val newCols = df.columns.map(c => if (c.startsWith("_")) col(c) as c.drop(1) else col(c))
val newDf = df.select(newCols:_*)
```

Just a matter of taste there.